# Image append is not working for directive in an ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

This is the div has the ng-repeat. I am trying to append an image to it for each file.

```
<div class = "fileslink" ng-repeat="file in files" id = "filegen" my-repeat-directive>
```

....

`
This creates the image, and is called on page load:

```
function filesInFolder(i){
                $scope.files = [];
                $http.get("/restricted/getFileList?folder=" + i + "&withComments=True")
                .then(function (response) {
                    if (response.data.status != 'Failed' && response.data != []){
                        for (var j=0; j<response.data.length; j++){
                            var newFile = {};
                            newFile.fileName = response.data[j].fileName;
                            newFile.folder = i;
                            //alert("folder: " + newFile.folder);
                            newFile.comment = response.data[j].comment;
                            newFile.selected = false;
                            newFile.editingComment = false;
                            newFile.date = getDate(newFile.fileName, newFile.folder);
                            $scope.files.push(newFile);
                            var imageElem = document.createElement("img");
                            imageElem.src = "/Additional%20Files/icons/" + fileType(response.data[j].fileName) + ".png";

                            console.log(response.data[j].fileName);
                            imageElem.height = "37";
                            imageElem.width = "31";
                            imageElem.style.position = "absolute";
                            imageElem.style.top = "7px";
                            imageElem.style.left = "18px";
                            imageElem.style.paddingBottom = "2px";
                            imageElem.style.border = "2px solid black";
                            console.log("name inside folder: " + response.data[j].fileName + ", src: " +imageElem.src);

                        }
                    }
                }); 
            };
```

**Directive**

```
app.directive('myRepeatDirective', function() {
    var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("fileslink");
    //console.log(boxes.length);
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        for (var x = 0; x < boxes.length; x++) {
            console.log("x: " + x + ", val: ");
            boxes[x].appendChild(imageElement);
        };
        angular.element(element).css('border', '2px solid red');
        if (scope.$last) {
            window.alert("im the last!");
        }
    };
});
```

Right now the image only shows on the very first file, (index 0), and not the others. What am I missing here?

Still new to angular btw so if you have any more efficient ways to write the code, that would help.

Comment: There's no creation of a `imageElement` in the loop?

Comment: It gets created in another function, this is just a snippet of my code (this is just one part of my project), so I didn't include it here.

Comment: If you keep appending the same image in the loop, you'll still only have one image ?

Comment: @rxa does `window.alert("im the last!");` is alerting once?

Comment: @PankajParkar Yes, once.

Comment: @rxa then here you go.. I added the answer...

Comment: @adeneo I think you are right, I was using the same image over, I have added the image creation code so hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You should wait till `ng-repeat` render all of its element. And then you should append an image element. You already had a condition which check `ng-repeat` completes its rendering, `if(scope.$last)` is a condition which indicates all element of `ng-repeat` has been rendered.

**Directive**

```
app.directive('myRepeatDirective', function() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        angular.element(element).css('border', '2px solid red');
        if (scope.$last) {
            var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("fileslink");
            window.alert("im the last!");
            console.log(boxes.length); //all element must be rendered
            for (var x = 0; x < boxes.length; x++) {
                console.log("x: " + x + ", val: ");
                boxes[x].appendChild(imageElement);
            };
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: This makes sense, but it is still only showing the image for the last index

Comment: @rxa  you also need to move `var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("fileslink");` document query inside a `if(scope.$last)` condition. to make it working

Comment: Yes it does return the right number, and when I do console.log(boxes[x]) it returns the correct divs associated with it, but for some reason it still isn't adding the image